# React native not receiving connect call back with socket io

Tags: react-native, websocket, socket.io

It seems like there are some issues with React Native 0.58 and above with socket io. I was able to receive a connection on my flask socket app.

```
(10986) accepted ('219.75.15.152', 60929)
219.75.15.152 - - [24/Jul/2019 14:44:12] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 200 0 74.207503
(10986) accepted ('219.75.15.152', 61254)
```

But I could not receive the console output for successful connection. On client, I am using the snippet below

```js
const userSocket = io('http://MYSERVER.com/user_update', {
        reconnect: true,
        transports: ['websocket']
      }).then(() => {
        userSocket.on('connection', (socket) => {
          console.log("test")
          alert("receive")
        });  
        userSocket.emit("join", this.state.myToken);
      })
```

P.S I was wondering if anybody tried this on react native 0.59.9 or ^0.60. Does socket io only work for 0.57.*?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I can confirm that it works on react native 0.59.9. Just gotta make sure that CORS is enabled on the flask-socketio backend.